# XAMPP/MYSQL - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

So yesterday I was working on my project, everything went fine, so I just went to sleep. I woke up, done my things and when I tried to run apache and mysql (through xampp), apache did start, but mysql shows an error like this:

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
[mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
[mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
[mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
[mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
[mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
[mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

I did absolutely nothing since yesterday, so I have no idea what went wrong. Also, I've checked Windows Event Viewer, and came up with those results:

```
Warning
Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!! Please use '--log-basename=#' or '--relay-log=mysql-relay-bin' to avoid this problem. 

Error (this one repeats itself couple of times)
Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593  

Error
Failed to create a new master info file (file 'D:\Programs\xampp\mysql\data\master-2019@002d12@002d27@002020@003a50@003a29@00209@0020@005berror@005d@0020mysqld@002eexe@003a@0020table@0020@0027@002e@005clsslspd@005cwqhndjvxchcv_users@0027@0020is@0020marked@0020as@0020crashed@0020and@0020should@0020be@0020repaired@000d.info', errno 2)

Error
Initialized Master_info from 'master-2019@002d12@002d27@002020@003a50@003a29@00209@0020@005berror@005d@0020mysqld@002eexe@003a@0020table@0020@0027@002e@005clsslspd@005cwqhndjvxchcv_users@0027@0020is@0020marked@0020as@0020crashed@0020and@0020should@0020be@0020repaired@000d.info' failed

Error
Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593 

Error
Failed to create a new master info file (file 'D:\Programs\xampp\mysql\data\master-2019@002d12@002d27@002022@003a53@003a23@0020125@0020@005bwarning@005d@0020aborted@0020connection@0020125@0020to@0020db@003a@0020@0027lsslspd@0027@0020user@003a@0020@0027root@0027@0020host@003a@0020@0027localhost@0027@0020@0028got@0020an@0020error@0020reading@0020communication@0020packets@0029@000d.info', errno 2)
```

Last two errors repeats themselves 4 times alternately (but with slight different values)

Could you guys help me with this one? I dont want to lost all of my data. Already tried reinstalling and copying content of mysql->data but it doesnt work.

Comment: The same thing happened to me today.  I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 17):

With `mysql` not started, check if there `xampp/mysql/data/multi-master.info` file exists, and delete it. This worked for me.

Comment: This worked for Event Viewer error: "Failed to create a new master info file"

Comment: This one worked for me too

Comment: The question is why this is even there.. hmm... is there any explanation for it?